# Caching options

Tags: caching, smarty

As I see Smarty uses caching ‘by template’.

Can I somehow provide an URL to it, so it would cache pages by the URL given?
Can I get `is_cached()` to work with that given URL?

And compare `last_mtime` of the cached file with some of my data and then say «it’s time to update the cache»?

Comment: Thanks, I knew my english is poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As default Smarty uses file based caching while storing php-like files in the `$cache_dir`.

You can implement a [custom cache function](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/caching.custom.tpl) and [register it](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.cacheresource.tpl), but that depends on your desire how deep you want to dive into Smarty.

A way easier approach would be to just add a bit of the urls name to the template filename, so in your template directory for example might look like.

```
/your/templates/url1.index.tpl
/your/templates/url2.index.tpl
```

...and then use Smartys caching according to your needs.